# Remove node from XML with Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm just wondering if it is possible to remove a node from XML with Jquery without having to replace the whole file every time? For example, if i have an xml file

```
<ArrivingFlights>
<flight>
    <to>Michelle</to>
    <from>Brianna xx</from>
    <imagepath>0001.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>17:00</time>
    <date>18/12/15</date>
</flight>
 <flight>
    <to>Ger</to>
    <from>Mammy xx</from>
    <imagepath>0002.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>08:00</time>
    <date>21/12/15</date>
</flight>
<flight>
    <to>Ciara</to>
    <from>Vikki xx</from>
    <imagepath>0003.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>11:00</time>
    <date>17/12/15</date>
</flight>
</ArrivingFlights>
```

Would it be possible to just remove the below so there will just be 2 nodes?

```
<flight>
    <to>Michelle</to>
    <from>Brianna xx</from>
    <imagepath>0001.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>17:00</time>
    <date>18/12/15</date>
</flight>
```

I am thinking of doing this on a bigger scale so would like to learn ho to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual element in your code as in the answer below, `document.createElement()` or `jQuery('<tag>', {options})` will do. You can put the `xml` data in it then just use a each loop to find the desired text and remov the parent xml tag which holds it.

You can use this:

```js
var xmlData = '<ArrivingFlights><flight><to>Michelle</to> <from>Brianna xx</from>    <imagepath>0001.jpg</imagepath>    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>    <time>17:00</time>    <date>18/12/15</date></flight> <flight>    <to>Ger</to>    <from>Mammy xx</from>    <imagepath>0002.jpg</imagepath>    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>    <time>08:00</time>    <date>21/12/15</date></flight><flight>    <to>Ciara</to>    <from>Vikki xx</from>    <imagepath>0003.jpg</imagepath>    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>    <time>11:00</time>    <date>17/12/15</date></flight></ArrivingFlights>';
var xml = $('<div>', {
  html: xmlData
});

$(xml).find('flight').each(function() {
  if ($('to', this).text() === "Michelle") {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});

$('pre').text(xml.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

---

As per your comment:

*I'm loading the xml through Ajax, its in another file*

You can call the same action in your ajax success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  /// other options
   success:function(xmlData){
       var xml = $('<div>', { html: xmlData  });  // create a virtual element
       $(xml).find('flight').each(function() {  // loop through the parent elems
           if ($('to', this).text() === "Michelle") { // check the text
               $(this).remove(); // now remove it.
           }
       });

       // here you can do anything with the var xml.

   }
});
```

Comment: I'm loading the xml through Ajax, its in another file

Comment: no worries you can do this in the success callback then.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Try this out:

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: xml_url,
        success: function(data) {
          var $flights = $('flight', data);
          $flights.each(function() {
            if ($('to', this).text() == "Michelle") {
              $(this).remove();
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: I'm loading the xml through Ajax, its in another file